# wso2 esb deploy failed on windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, wso2, esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 with JDK 1.7.0_67 x64 on windows 7 x64.
I'm deploying carbon application(.car) using any method:

1. maven car deploy plugin
2. web admin console
3. CarbonAppUploader web service

First deployment succeeds but log file contains:

```
CarbonAppUploader temp file: C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..\tmp\carbonappsuploads\first-esb_1.0.0.car deletion failed, scheduled deletion on server exit.
```

Second deployment of same car (name and version) fails with exception in logs (see below)

I Apologize for localized error message but generally it says cant overwrite this file.

If you check, it's actually locked for deletion. Looks like CarbonAppUploader class didn't properly close InputStream.

Strangely enough this bug is not reproducible in unix (centos)

**Question to WSO2: do you plan to fix that?**

Question to all: Did you meet such bug and how did you solve it?

exception stack trace (partially)

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-08-18 22:04:58,254] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.upload.CarbonAppUploader} -  Error occurred while uploading Carbon App artifacts {org.wso2.carbon.application.upload.CarbonAppUploader}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Java\WSO2ES~1.1\bin\..\tmp\carbonappsuploads\first-esb_1.0.0.car (Запрошенную операцию нельзя выполнить для файла с открытой пользователем сопоставленной секцией)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.upload.CarbonAppUploader.writeResource(CarbonAppUploader.java:78)
at org.wso2.carbon.application.upload.CarbonAppUploader.uploadApp(CarbonAppUploader.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked out source code from svn, fixed bug myself. If anybody experiencing same issue, you may download sources and compiled jar from https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3272
Hopefully this bug fix will be included in next releases